# Can I increase the 10 event limit in Simon Monk's Timer library?

Tags: library

On Dr. Monk's library page [here](http://www.doctormonk.com/2012/01/arduino-timer-library.html), he states: "You can attach up to 10 events to a timer." I am wondering if this is a hardware limit, or if it was an arbitrary number he chose for his library.

In Timer.h, he defines the maximum number of timed events like this:

```
#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_EVENTS (10)
```

Can you foresee any problems if I changed that to a higher number? My sketch is already approaching the limit of 10 timed events running at the same time, so it would help me if I was able to increase the maximum number of timed events to about 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything that would cause any issue. Just don't exceed 255.

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark this as the answer if I don't notice any problems by tomorrow. I wonder why he would choose such a low arbitrary number. Even the forked updated versions on github keep the 10 limit.

Comment: This is due to memory. The library creates 10 `Event` objects and stores them in an array. That is at least 11 bytes per object.